# Is it possible to refresh the outline view only when file is saved (and not during editing)?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm developing a vscode extension for a custom language and I provide symbols by registering a  [vscode.DocumentSymbolProvider](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#DocumentSymbolProvider).

I have noticed that my symbol provider is called by vscode *every* time the content of the current file is *changed* in order to refresh the [outline view](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_outline-view).

I would like to change this behaviour to refresh the outline view only when the current file is *saved*. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no setting for this. If you'd like to see it supported, please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose)

However it's entirely up to your extension when and how to compute the outline. Your extension could cache the document symbol data and return the cached version when VS Code asks, only re-computing new document symbol data on file save

Comment: Would you know how to trigger refresh of the outline view from an extension ? Thanks